# MvvmCross Monotouch - Fail to bind Properties on a real iPad, but it works on the Simulator

Tags: c#, xamarin.ios, mvvmcross

I am working with MvvmCross Monotouch.

Here is the Binding Code that actually works very well on the iOS Simulator.

```
{ this, "{'Title':{'Path':'NavigationBarTitle'}}
```

However, it does not work when I deploy it on my real iPad (iPad 2).

```
Application Output:
===================
MvxBind: Warning:   0.69 Failed to create target binding for from NavigationBarTitle to Title
```

I am glad to see it works on the iOS Simulator but, is there any reason why it does not work on the real iPad?

Patrick

Answer (score 7, accepted):

One situation I've seen this type of error occur in is in release builds where the monotouch linker optimises the image size and removes the apparently unused property required for binding.

To workaround this, I generally include a fake bit of code to trick the linker into including the required properties - e.g. Here's a monodroid sample file which does the same sort of thing:

https://github.com/slodge/MvvmCross/blob/master/Sample%20-%20BestSellers/BestSellers/BestSellers.Droid/LinkerIncludePlease.cs

This is one of the disadvantages of using mvvmcross currently - it can lead to larger binary image sizes.

Comment: I am trying to understand how the LinkerIncludePlease class works. I am downloading MonoDroid and I will check the project adn see how it could help me.

Comment: Basically the linker is not seeing any code referencing Title so it removes that property and does not aot include it - but the app does then actually try to use Title at runtime using reflection and that's when the problem happens. I can't find the hyoerlink I'm really looking for, but some useful links are http://docs.xamarin.com/ios/advanced_topics/linker and http://spouliot.wordpress.com/2011/08/11/when-to-link-monotouch-applications/

Comment: Hi @Stuart, thanks for the info about the linker. It's something I did not know. I read a some stuff here :
http://docs.xamarin.com/ios/advanced_topics/linker
Then, I went to: Project -> Options > Build -> iPhoneBuild -> Linker Behavior -> "Don't link".
It fixed the linker problem. However, I hope this is not a bad practice and that it won't bring performance weakness or something bad. I am going to test this like this for now. But perhaps, there are preserve attributes that are missing in the mvvmcross library that need to be added to prevent the linker to remove unused code.

Comment: Yes - I agree - I never use "don't link" in a released application. From your description, I think what is being removed by the linker is the `Title` property - which is a property on a MonoTouch-wrapped UIKit object? If that's true, then the challenge is how to get the linker to include this property. To get this to work I generally set the linker to "SDK assemblies only" and then include a file like LinkerIncludePlease.cs - that file contains the classes, properties, and methods that I need the linker to include.

Comment: To give a further explanation to that last answer... when testing the Conference app in release mode I found that `Click` wasn't working on binding for my views - so that's why LinkerIncludePlease.cs includes a method which adds a delegate to `view.Click` - this just tricks the linker into including that event in the linked application.