# Using MVVMCross IoC with Link All Assemblies

Tags: mvvmcross

I'm just reading up about the [inbuilt IoC of MVVM Cross](https://github.com/MvvmCross/MvvmCross/wiki/Service-Location-and-Inversion-of-Control) and how it makes heavy use of reflection. Just wondering, does this cause issues with [Xamarin linking](http://docs.xamarin.com/guides/ios/advanced_topics/linker/)? What are people finding best practise in this area? Using "Link SDK assemblies only" or perhaps configuring IoC in a way that avoids reflection?

Thanks in advance :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Both MvvmCross IoC and MvvmCross binding rely on Reflection.

Because of this, users often use "Link SDK assemblies only" and often use "LinkerPleaseIgnore" files.

You can read more about this on:

- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10224376/mvvmcross-experiences-hindsight-limitations/10225623#10225623
- [Problems with mvvmcross Binding on IOS (Works on Simulator, but some properties doesn't work on the Device)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14275499/problems-with-mvvmcross-binding-on-ios-works-on-simulator-but-some-properties/14277456#14277456)
- ... and many more https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=[mvvmcross]+linker

The MvvmCross nuget packages ship with default "LinkerPleaseIgnore" files - e.g. https://github.com/MvvmCross/MvvmCross/blob/v3.1/nuspec/TouchContent/LinkerPleaseInclude.cs.pp

Comment: While this works for bindings it seems to fail for me when using plugins.