# MvvmCross Android Button Click binding not working in Release build

Tags: android, xamarin.android, mvvmcross

Following on this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14208203/mvvmcross-android-alternative-to-relativesource-binding-for-button-command), I have built the application in Release and published to a Samsung Galaxy Tab 2 10.1, Android version 4.0.4, and the button click command does not fire. I even put a dialog fragment in there and the command is not actually executed.

When I debug the same app on the same device, it works fine.

Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please see:

- [Problems with mvvmcross Binding on IOS (Works on Simulator, but some properties doesn't work on the Device)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14275499/problems-with-mvvmcross-binding-on-ios-works-on-simulator-but-some-properties)
- [MvvmCross Monotouch - Fail to bind Properties on a real iPad, but it works on the Simulator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11349864/mvvmcross-monotouch-fail-to-bind-properties-on-a-real-ipad-but-it-works-on-th)

Linker issues like this also mentioned in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10224376/mvvmcross-experiences-hindsight-limitations

Comment: I have the same problem I add the class LinkerPleaseInclude.cs and when I built the application in release and publish my ImageButton command does not fires, how I can resolve this problem? I use ImageButton
public IMvxCommand Informacion { get { return ShowCommand<InformacionViewModel>(); } }