# Mvvmcross Android Togglebutton binding doesn't seem to work in release mode

Tags: android, xamarin, mvvmcross, togglebutton

I have a strange behaviour in the sense that an app which works perfectly fine in debug mode behaves differently when in release mode. More in particular, I use a couple of  togglebuttons with dual property binding for which the binding works when compiled and deployed for debug while it doesn't anymore when in release mode. All other used widgets, including normal buttons  seem to work just fine.  AXML snippet for one of the buttons here included:

```
                    <ToggleButton
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="80dp"
                    android:id="@+id/bindtoggleeco"
                    local:MvxBind="Click EcoToggleCommand;Checked EcoModeToggle"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="30dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="30dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
                    android:textSize="25sp" />
```

What could cause such behaviour ? I honestly have no clue where to start looking as it works perfectly fine when debugging... Also don't know whether it's the Click property binding that fails or the Checked one.

EDIT: Some more info: 
- behaviour is observed in 4.0.3;4.1.2 and 4.2.2 with minimum & target API set to 4.0.3
- I seem to get hundreds of messages in the outputwindow that weren't there bin debug mode (Visual studio is connected to the emulator for testing)
"02-27 01:04:37.812 W/Trace   ( 2044): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0"

Comment: Try adding this event handler explicitly to LinkerPleaseInclude - see other questions on here like http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14291696/mvvmcross-android-button-click-binding-not-working-in-release-build and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15613694/android-app-is-too-large-and-linking-disables-functionality

Comment: Thx Stuart. That did it ! I should have searched a bit better I guess but still, awesome support from your side. I needed this code to do a customer demo at 9am, just made it in time...