# MvxBind for ToggleButton fails only in Release build

Tags: android, data-binding, mvvmcross

In my Android MvvmCross app, my ToggleButton bindings work like a champ for Debug builds, but fail for Release.

My ToggleButton and binding definition is similar to the following:

```
    <ToggleButton
        android:id="@+id/MyToggle"
        local:MvxBind="Checked MyToggleChecked" />
```

If I enable debug output for my release build, I get see the following log output:

```
MvxBind:Error:113.19 View type not found - ToggleButton
[0:] MvxBind:Error:113.19 View type not found - ToggleButton
03-04 14:38:41.005 I/mono-stdout(25265): MvxBind:Error:113.19 View type not found - ToggleButton
```

My MvvmCross assemblies are version v4.0.30319, my MvvmCross.Droid assemblies are v2.0.50727 (Hmm... is that a problem?)

Any ideas?  (Thanks in advance to Suart. ;-)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22056747/mvvmcross-android-togglebutton-binding-doesnt-seem-to-work-in-release-mode

Comment: Wow, my search didn't come across that one.  I'll give it a shot!  Thank you!

Comment: We should probably update the error message to ask "Have you added the type to LinkerPleaseInclude?"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per the link Stuart Lodge's comment, the problem is due to the linker not including the reflected property referenced in the MvxBind expression.

I added a class with an explicit reference to the property to force inclusion by the linker, now all is well with my Release build!

```
internal class LinkerForceInclude
{
    private LinkerForceInclude()
    {            
    }

    private void IncludeChecked(ToggleButton button)
    {
        button.Checked = !button.Checked;
    }
}
```